# ComboBox.SelectedItem no longer relevant?

Tags: c#

Good Afternoon,

I am using a ComboBox in visual studio to determine whether a user can use a text field below it on a form.

The Combobox "ReasonBox" is bound to a datasource and sql query that selects the allowed "Reasons" to choose from.

Before I had the dynamic selections I was using:

```
private void ReasonBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ReasonBox.SelectedValue != null)   `
        if (ReasonBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Other")
        {
             { ReasonTextBox.Enabled = true; }
             { ReasonTextBox.BackColor = Color.White; }
        }
}
```

to enable writing to the TextBox when "Other" was selected.

Unfortuantely now I am unable to figure out how to make this happen with my databound ReasonBox. Any Ideas?

Edit: Thanks for the help guys, I think i've found the reason:

```
ReasonBox_SelectedIndexChanged
```

Appears to not be triggering when I change the selection. I'll investigate further in the morning :)

Comment: did you try `ReasonBox.SelectedText` ?

Comment: I did and unfortunately it doesn't behave, Value.ToString() doesn't either. I had some fake success with index but as the ReasonBox can have different numbers of options it isn't reliable.

Comment: Two things... please show your front end code for the combobox... 2nd when exactly are you binding the data to the combobox (i suspect this is your issue)

Comment: Also, in questions related to a UI toolkit, please add the appropriate tag for the UI toolkit (I *strongly suspect* you are using Windows Forms here) to your question.

Comment: SelectedText will only work if DropDownStyle is NOT set to DropDownList.

Comment: Questions: How are you doing the databinding? Do you set DisplayMember and ValueMember to anything? What exactly is the box bound to? For example, is it a List<Reason> or a DataTable with rows from the database?

Comment: I'm binding to a table in my database with 2 columns, ID and Description. Display Member set to "Description", ValueMember to ID.
I then added a query which selects ID and Reasons based on criteria in the Load Form (which allows/disallows certain 'reasons')

Comment: The important thing is what .NET object you're binding to. If it's a DataTable, then SelectedItem will return a DataRow. ToString() will almost definitely NOT return "Other" for a DataRow.

Answer (score 1):

Try **SelectedText**

You can find the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

`ReasonBox.Text == "Other"`

Text property gets or sets the text associated with this control.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"ReasonBox.Text" == "Other"
```

OR

```
ReasonBox.Items[ReasonBox.SelectedIndex].ToString() == "Other"
```

Insted of

```
ReasonBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Other"
```